# Purpose of focusInEvent and focusOutEvent in QQuickItem

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget, qquickitem

Its basic Qt5 question, some explanation how they behave will be good.

I am confused with focusInEvent/focusOutEvent in case of QQuickItem. since QQuickItem has concept of activefocus which get notified to item with ItemChanged event, also focusInEvent/focusOutEvent are only triggred when activeFocus is true for QQuickItem else item won't receive those event.

Also I faced some scenario when focusOutEvent comes but it doesn't change
activeFocus of Item.

How does focusInEvent/focusOutEvent relate to active focus of item and what is the based method to check for QuickItem focus/unfocus, rely on activeFocus OR assume focusOutEvent ?